# SQL Reading .txt files and separation the data inside

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've some .txt files in a folder and i wanna to sequentially open them and separate the data into the DB (4)attributes 
Sample of my code that read and split one file:

```
CREATE TABLE movie_titles
(
ID varchar(100) NOT NULL ,
ProductionYear Varchar (max) NOT NULL ,
Name Varchar (max) NOT NULL
)
GO 
BULK INSERT movie_titles FROM 'C:\Users\ PC\Desktop\nf_prize_dataset\download\movie_titles.txt'
WITH 
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',' ,
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
SELECT * FROM movie_titles
GO
DROP TABLE movie_titles
GO
```

Comment: What is your question?  What have you tried?

Comment: Post your code and sample data in these files.

Comment: i need to know how to do this i can read from one .txt file only

Comment: We still need to see your data in this one file to tell you how to parse it

Comment: numbers separated with comma
1488844,3,2005-09-06